# Change color of background PNG using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set a background image on a web page, changing his color to B/W with:

```
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

It works until i put another image that should have his original colors. I try to use:

```
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
```

Also with the !important attribute the filter used is the first one belong to the content.

You can look at this code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CIiwE
It's so strange the fact that if i set background image with grayscale 0% and the upper image with 100% it works fine, but i need the opposite.
Thanks

**EDIT.**
Thanks to webkit for your answer. I post the solution that has worked fine for me based on webkit's solution.

## HTML

```html
<div class='boo'>
      <img id='imgbkgr' src="http://placekitten.com/300/300"></img>
</div>
        
<div id="content">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/100/100);">
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.boo {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
position: absolute;
padding:0px;
padding-top:0px;
top:0;
}
        
#content{
margin-top: 1em;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
display:block;
width: 100%;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: your img is INSIDE the containing div with grayscale filter.. the filter works on everything inside the container.. you can't unfilter something inside..

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: well.. first of all, your original IMG is black and white.. so I'd suggest testing on actual colored photo.. lol. update your question with color photo and I'll try to help you.

Comment: LOL you're right, sry. I've update. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you are using id="foo" but in your css (.foo). Change your css it works fine

Comment: @srini - fixing the selector doesn't override the parent filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can just use the same background image..

what you need to do is take the img outside of the container..

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/webkit_il/pen/GxDjm)

Also, notice I fixed your html.. img doesn't need a closing tag.
Plus your css selector was .foo instead of #foo.

### html

```
<div class='boo'></div>
<img id="foo" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
```

### css

```
.boo {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300) no-repeat 0 0;
}

#foo{
  width:10%;
   position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
```

just a **side note**... I noticed if using only this:

```
#foo{
      width:10%;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    }
```

**the #foo img renders on top of the .boo element**, I guess it has something to do with stacking order, I'll be grateful if someone can fully explain this to me.

Comment: The stacking order changing is interesting. Unexpected, but correct. From the W3 Spec - The application of the ‘filter’ property to an element formatted with the CSS box model establishes a new stacking context the same way that CSS ‘opacity’ does, and all the element's descendants are rendered together as a group with the filter effect applied to the group as a whole.    - Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-filter-effects-20130523/